# Hide x-axis when it has no value on chart.js

Tags: jquery, charts, chart.js

The label on my chart starts in the year 2016, but the data only 
starts in the year 2018, so my chart displays as follows

[image]

I wanted him to only start counting from the year that there is data and ignore it when it is null, I used **beginAtzero** but I was not successful.

My cod

```
var chart1 = new Chart(document.getElementById("pga6").getContext("2d"), {
    type: "line",
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            bezierCurve: false,
             scales: {
                 xAxes: [{
                     display: true,
                     scaleLabel: {
                         display: true
                     },
                     ticks: {
                         maxTicksLimit:5,
                         minTicksLimit:1,
                         fontSize:12,
                         weight:100,
                         maxRotation: 0,
                         minRotation: 0
                     },
                     angleLines: {
                         lineWidth: 1
                     },
                     gridLines: {
                         display: false,
                     }
                 }]
             }
        },
    data: {
      labels: ['01/01/2016','01/02/2016','01/01/2016','01/01/2016','01/01/2016','01/01/2016'...........'01/01/2018',],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Participantes ativos",
          data: [,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,5596,5307,5046,4901,4580,4151,],
          fill: false,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(32, 77, 155, 1)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(32, 77, 155, 1)',
          borderWidth: 2,
                    lineTension: 0.4,
        }
    ]
  },
});
```

What i need?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. This is a data problem. There are a few empty values in your `data`:

```js
data: [,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,5596,5307,5046,4901,4580,4151,]
```

The result is a few empty points before the points with real data appear, like this:

```js
var config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'APAC RE Index',
                backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
                borderColor: "#ff00000",
                fill: false,
                data: [,,,
                    10,
                    50,
                    30,
                    60,
                    100,
                    50,
                    150
                ],
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Chart.js Line Chart - Logarithmic'
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Date'
          },
            
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    //type: 'logarithmic',
          scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Index Returns'
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            min: 0,
                            max: 200,

                            // forces step size to be 5 units
                            stepSize: 100
                        }
                }]
            }
        }
    };

    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/476360/utils.js"></script>
        <canvas id="canvas" style="display: block; width: 1379px; height: 689px;" width="1379" height="689" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></canvas>
    
<script src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/476360/Chart.js"></script>
```

Simply remove these points:

```js
var config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'APAC RE Index',
                backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
                borderColor: "#ff00000",
                fill: false,
                data: [
                    10,
                    50,
                    30,
                    60,
                    100,
                    50,
                    150
                ],
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Chart.js Line Chart - Logarithmic'
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Date'
          },
            
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    //type: 'logarithmic',
          scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Index Returns'
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            min: 0,
                            max: 200,

                            // forces step size to be 5 units
                            stepSize: 100
                        }
                }]
            }
        }
    };

    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/476360/Chart.js"></script>

        <canvas id="canvas" style="display: block; width: 1379px; height: 689px;" width="1379" height="689" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></canvas>
```

Otherwise, if data begins later in time then just delete earlier labels as there is no need for them to be there. For example, if data begins in May:

```js
var config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'APAC RE Index',
                backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
                borderColor: "#ff00000",
                fill: false,
                data: [
                    100,
                    50,
                    150
                ],
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Chart.js Line Chart - Logarithmic'
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Date'
          },
            
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    //type: 'logarithmic',
          scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Index Returns'
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            min: 0,
                            max: 200,

                            // forces step size to be 5 units
                            stepSize: 100
                        }
                }]
            }
        }
    };

    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/476360/utils.js"></script>
        <canvas id="canvas" style="display: block; width: 1379px; height: 689px;" width="1379" height="689" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></canvas>
    
<script src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/476360/Chart.js"></script>
```

If data comes from an external source you can create a function to delete unneeded values. Here is a *rudimentary* example where `fixData()` will delete unneded `data` and `labels` values:

```js
var globalLabels = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July']
var globalData = [,,,
                    10,
                    50,
                    30,
                    60,
                    100,
                    50,
                    150
                ]

function fixData() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= globalData.length; i++) {
    if (globalData[i] === undefined) {
      globalData.splice(0, 1)
      globalLabels.splice(0, 1)
    }
  }
}

fixData()

var config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: globalLabels,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'APAC RE Index',
                backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
                borderColor: "#ff00000",
                fill: false,
                data: globalData,
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Chart.js Line Chart - Logarithmic'
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Date'
          },
            
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    //type: 'logarithmic',
          scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Index Returns'
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            min: 0,
                            max: 200,

                            // forces step size to be 5 units
                            stepSize: 100
                        }
                }]
            }
        }
    };

    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/476360/utils.js"></script>
        <canvas id="canvas" style="display: block; width: 1379px; height: 689px;" width="1379" height="689" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></canvas>
    
<script src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/476360/Chart.js"></script>
```

Comment: The data comes to me with ASP.NET, I can't handle it before I put it in the graphics, I wanted some way to hide it through javascript

Comment: I see. You can use a function to remove unneeded values. See last snippet.

Comment: It worked well for me, using only one globalDate, but what about when it's two?

Comment: What you mean with two? There should be only one pair of `data` and `labels` for a chart.

Comment: Two date fields, something like a line chart with two data on two different lines.

An example of what I am having is, a bar graph with two different data, his answer is
var globalData3 = [,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,955.14897527,];

var globalData3_1 = [,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,-2563.48363779,-4537.03674119,-5318.03537764,-4771.078952,-5485.97820398,-5240.54627608,- 3510.24686536,-4071.58133361,-5855.83296102,-4532.54903394,-4629.83432044];

Comment: That looks like another question. The original question only has 1 set of data. Can you want to open a new question with two sets of data?